# Using a class on multiple WPF pages

Tags: c#, wpf

All:

I am working on a user interface to control a videoconferencing codec using wpf. For this example I only have to pages. One main page which as some shortcuts and basic controls and an advanced page.

Here's my problem, I instantiate the codec control class on the main page, but it's not accessible on the advanced page. I don't know how to make the codec control class available to both pages.

Here's a snippet (I didn't include namespace for clarity)

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using CodecControl;

public partial class MainWindow:Window
{
    Codec codec = new Codec();

    public MainWindow();
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdvanced_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _mainframe.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Advanced.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
    }

    //there are various shortcut buttons below here
}
```

AdvancedPage

```
 public partial class AdvancedPage : Page
 {
    InitializeComponent();
 }

 private void btnConnect(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     codec.Connect(ipAddress,port);
 }
 //other controls below
```

It seems that I should be able to instantiate the class once then use it on other pages since they'll all part of the same main window. What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.
Norm

Answer (score 0):

Based on the incomplete code example provided, there's only one mechanism that seems directly applicable. That is, use the `NavigationService.Navigate(Uri, Object)` overload:

```
public partial class MainWindow:Window
{
    Codec codec = new Codec();

    public MainWindow();
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdvanced_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _mainframe.NavigationService.Navigated += NavigationService_Navigated;
        _mainframe.NavigationService.Navigate(
            new Uri("Advanced.xaml", UriKind.Relative), codec);
    }

    private void NavigationService_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ((AdvancedPage)e.Content).Codec = (Codec)e.ExtraData;
        _mainframe.NavigationService.Navigated -= NavigationService_Navigated;
    }

    //there are various shortcut buttons below here
}
```

Note that for the above to work, your `AdvancedPage` class needs a `Codec` property that can be used to set the `Codec` reference.

Another alternative that *might* work, depending on why you chose to use the `Uri` overload, is to create the `AdvancedPage` object yourself and pass that to the `Navigate(Object)` method:

```
_mainframe.NavigationService.Navigate(new AdvancedPage(codec));
```

Obviously, you'd need to add a constructor to your `AdvancedPage` class to take the `Codec` reference as an argument.

Or you could use a hybrid of the two above, by having the `AdvancedPage.Codec` property, but assigning it to a locally-created `AdvancedPage` object before navigating to that object. Then you only need to add the property, instead of a new constructor.

If none of that seems useful in your scenario, you'll need to improve your question, so that it includes a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).